# Lock for reading, writing and exclusivity

Tags: c++, database, transactions, locking

I need to implement three different types of locking. Lock for reading, writing and exclusivity. For example, there is an abstract object named table and many transactions work from different threads.

1. A read lock is a lock that allows you to simultaneously read data from different transactions, but if one of the transactions requires a table for writing, it needs to wait until all read locks are removed.
2. The write lock allows any transaction to read from the table, but only one transaction that owns the table for writing can write to the table
3. And an exclusive lock is a lock when only one transaction has access to the table, and others wait when the lock is removed.

And I'm looking for how this can be implemented using WinApi and C/C++ i am trying like that

```
class Table
{
void LockWrite()
{
    if (LockLW.IsLock())
        LockLW.wait_and_lock();
    //
    if (LockEx.IsLock())
        LockEx.wait();
}
void LockExclusive()
{
    {
        // it is assumed that this is a thread-safe check
        if (readers != 0)
            FreeLockRead.wait();
    }
    //but there is a problem, because in this place some transactions have started to read again

    if (LockLW.IsLock())
        LockLW.wait_and_lock();

    if (LockEx.IsLock())
        LockEx.wait_and_lock();
}

void UnLockExclusive()
{
    LockEx.unLock();
}

void LockRead()
{
    if (LockEx.IsLock())
        LockEx.wait();
    //Set Lock Read
    //a problem, because in this place one of transactions have got LockEx
    readers += 1;
}

void UnLockRead()
{
    readers -= 1;
    if (readers == 0)
        FreeLockRead.pulse();
}

mutex LockLW;
mutex LockEx;

event FreeLockRead;
atomic  readers;
};
```

Comment: Will something like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

After studying the materials, I found the following solution:

```
class Table
{
enum eFlag
{
    eFree = 0,
    eRead = 1,
    eWrite = 2,
    eExclusive = 4
};
uint32_t m_nReaders;
std::mutex m_Mutex;
uint32_t m_nFlag;
std::condition_variable m_condition;

void LockForRead()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
    if (m_nFlag & eExclusive)
    {
        m_condition.wait(lk, [this]() {return !(m_nFlag & eExclusive); });
    }
    m_nReaders += 1;
    m_nFlag |= eRead;
}
void UnLockForRead()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);

    assert(m_nReaders != 0 && (m_nFlag & eRead));

    m_nReaders -= 1;
    if (m_nReaders == 0)
    {
        m_nFlag &= ~eRead;
        m_condition.notify_one();
    }
}
void LockForExclusive()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
    if (m_nFlag != eFree)
        m_condition.wait(lk, [this]() {return m_nFlag == eFree; });

    m_nFlag = eExclusive;
}
void UnLockForExclusive()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);

    assert(m_nFlag == eExclusive);

    m_nFlag = eFree;
    m_condition.notify_all();
}
void LockForWrite()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);

    if (m_nFlag & (eExclusive | eWrite))
        m_condition.wait(lk, [this]() {return !(m_nFlag & (eExclusive | eWrite)); });

    m_nFlag |= eWrite;
}
void UnLockForWrite()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);

    assert(m_nFlag & eWrite);

    m_nFlag &= ~eWrite;
    m_condition.notify_one();
}
};
```